# Randomly selecting a a value from duplicates in a keyframe when performing a join

Tags: r, join, dplyr

I am looking to create a new location variable in a dataframe, using a key from a reference dataframe by suburb and postcode. However the reference dataframe has overlaps/duplicates in the key, due to the nature of geographical structures in Sydney, Australia. It looks something like this - postcode and suburb are the key variables, but there is overlap between them. I am assigning a suburb to my rows in my dataframe, from the reference df.

```
df <- tibble(vars = sample(c(1:5), 10, replace = T), 
             postcode = c(2022,2204,2016,2000,2007,2008,2022,2008,2008,2000))
df_ref <- tibble(postcode = c(2000,2000,2007,2008,2008,2022,2204),
                 suburb = c('Haymarket','Woolloomooloo','Ultimo','Darlington','Redfern','Bondi Jct','Marrickville'))
```

So far I have been merging the dataframes in a `left_join`, but doing some internal `dplyr` wrangling to filter the first of any overlaps:

```
df_join <- df %>%
  left_join(.,
            df_ref %>% 
              group_by(postcode) %>% 
              slice(1),
            by = 'postcode')
```

This doesn't quite do what I want to achieve, instead a solution that randomly selects one of the overlaps whenever one appears in the join, would be far more preferable.

`dplyr` / `tidyverse` language is preferable, but if `data.table` is the way, this might force my hand in sitting down to actually learn it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the two dataframes and for each row select any one random `suburb`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  left_join(df_ref, by = 'postcode') %>%
  group_by(row) %>%
  slice_sample(n = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want each row to get a potentially different match, then you'll probably need to do a full join, and then just subset to keep one of the matches afterward. For example

```
df %>%
  mutate(record_index = row_number()) %>% 
  left_join(df_ref) %>% 
  group_by(postcode) %>% 
  slice_sample(1) %>% 
  select(-record_index)
```